# C++ compiling and running in Sublime Text 2

Tags: c++, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I really like Sublime Text 2 for HTML/CSS and Python and I'm starting to learn C++ and I want to use Sublime Text 2. I have looked at a few tutorials on installing g++ in order to run C++ in Sublime Text 2.

This is my code:

```
// my first program in C++
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

And when I run it it says [Finished in 1.5s] but nothing got printed. I have added the environment variables path but nothing gets printed.

Comment: Try `std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;`

Comment: Just tried that and It still says [Finished in 0.8s]

Comment: Are you pressing `build` by any chance?

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot now. I must be too used to python building. Yes I was pressing `ctrl + b`. Thanks

Comment: No problem, I'll write an answer up and if you'd mark it as the solution I'd appreciate it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are pressing `build`, which compiles your source code into an executable but does not run it. The `[Finished in ...s]` you are seeing is how long the program took to compile.

What you need to do is `build` like you currently are, but then go to the directory where your source code is and run the executable file that's in there*. There is a `run` option within the editor, but it doesn't always work on Windows**.

<sub>*if the program closes instantly, try running it from the console or adding `std::cin.get()` to the end of your program</sub>
<sub>**often due to incorrect configuration</sub>

Comment: When I choose the run option it seems as if it compiles then runs automatically, thanks you.